# PyQt5 StackedWidget the first page border image does not work

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm using stacked widget with PyQt5 to realize a menu page and sub menu pages and i'm trying to set a welcome page that is shown once u run the application and switched to main menu page after 3 seconds.
the problem that i encoutered is that when i convert the .ui file to .py file and execute the script,  all pages border images are working fine except the welcome page border image ( it is not shown ) .

Note that i'm using Qt Designer

here is the error ...
this is the welcome page does not show the border image : 
[image]

and the other pages are working fine this one the other pages ( it shows its border image )  : 
[image]
thank you

code :

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'G:\Users\Mohamed.Souilem\Projects\Smart Updater - BLT SLT\smart updater UI\smartupdater.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_smartUpdaterUI(object):
    def setupUi(self, smartUpdaterUI):
        smartUpdaterUI.setObjectName("smartUpdaterUI")
        smartUpdaterUI.resize(667, 357)
        smartUpdaterUI.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(667, 357))
        smartUpdaterUI.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(667, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Ubuntu Mono")
        smartUpdaterUI.setFont(font)
        smartUpdaterUI.setToolTipDuration(0)
        smartUpdaterUI.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        smartUpdaterUI.setStyleSheet("color:white")
        smartUpdaterUI.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
        smartUpdaterUI.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Triangular)
        self.Main_menu = QtWidgets.QWidget(smartUpdaterUI)
        self.Main_menu.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/img/main menu.png);")
        self.Main_menu.setObjectName("Main_menu")
        self.deviceInfo_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Main_menu)
        self.deviceInfo_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(56, 44, 123, 119))
        self.deviceInfo_Button.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/img/info_button.png);")
        self.deviceInfo_Button.setText("")
        self.deviceInfo_Button.setObjectName("deviceInfo_Button")
        self.wifi_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Main_menu)
        self.wifi_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 44, 123, 119))
        self.wifi_Button.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/img/wifi_button.png);")
        self.wifi_Button.setText("")
        self.wifi_Button.setObjectName("wifi_Button")
        self.lan_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Main_menu)
        self.lan_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 44, 125, 119))
        self.lan_Button.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/img/lan_button.png);")
        self.lan_Button.setText("")
        self.lan_Button.setObjectName("lan_Button")
        self.power_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Main_menu)
        self.power_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(56, 200, 123, 119))
        self.power_Button.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/img/power_button.png);")
        self.power_Button.setText("")
        self.power_Button.setObjectName("power_Button")
        self.user_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Main_menu)
        self.user_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 200, 123, 119))
        self.user_Button.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/img/user_button.png);")
        self.user_Button.setText("")
        self.user_Button.setObjectName("user_Button")
        self.test_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Main_menu)
        self.test_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 200, 125, 119))
        self.test_Button.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/img/test_button.png);")
        self.test_Button.setText("")
        self.test_Button.setObjectName("test_Button")
        self.deviceInfo_text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.Main_menu)
        self.deviceInfo_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 170, 95, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Semibold")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.deviceInfo_text.setFont(font)
        self.deviceInfo_text.setStyleSheet("color:white ")
        self.deviceInfo_text.setObjectName("deviceInfo_text")
        self.wirelessConnection_text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.Main_menu)
        self.wirelessConnection_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(296, 170, 75, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Semibold")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.wirelessConnection_text.setFont(font)
        self.wirelessConnection_text.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.wirelessConnection_text.setStyleSheet("color:white ")
        self.wirelessConnection_text.setObjectName("wirelessConnection_text")
        self.lanConnection_text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.Main_menu)
        self.lanConnection_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 170, 31, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Semibold")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lanConnection_text.setFont(font)
        self.lanConnection_text.setStyleSheet("color:white ")
        self.lanConnection_text.setObjectName("lanConnection_text")
        self.powerOFF_text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.Main_menu)
        self.powerOFF_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(76, 328, 87, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Semibold")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.powerOFF_text.setFont(font)
        self.powerOFF_text.setStyleSheet("color:white ")
        self.powerOFF_text.setObjectName("powerOFF_text")
        self.user_text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.Main_menu)
        self.user_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(316, 328, 41, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Semibold")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.user_text.setFont(font)
        self.user_text.setStyleSheet("color:white ")
        self.user_text.setObjectName("user_text")
        self.test_text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.Main_menu)
        self.test_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(476, 328, 117, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Semibold")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.test_text.setFont(font)
        self.test_text.setStyleSheet("color:white ")
        self.test_text.setObjectName("test_text")
        self.menu_text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.Main_menu)
        self.menu_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(6, 6, 73, 19))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Reference Sans Serif")
        font.setPointSize(17)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.menu_text.setFont(font)
        self.menu_text.setObjectName("menu_text")
        smartUpdaterUI.setCentralWidget(self.Main_menu)

        self.retranslateUi(smartUpdaterUI)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(smartUpdaterUI)

    def retranslateUi(self, smartUpdaterUI):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        smartUpdaterUI.setWindowTitle(_translate("smartUpdaterUI", "Yamaichi Electronics Smart Updater "))
        self.deviceInfo_text.setText(_translate("smartUpdaterUI", "DEVICE INFO"))
        self.wirelessConnection_text.setText(_translate("smartUpdaterUI", "WIRELESS "))
        self.lanConnection_text.setText(_translate("smartUpdaterUI", "LAN"))
        self.powerOFF_text.setText(_translate("smartUpdaterUI", "POWER OFF"))
        self.user_text.setText(_translate("smartUpdaterUI", "USER"))
        self.test_text.setText(_translate("smartUpdaterUI", "TESTING MODE"))
        self.menu_text.setText(_translate("smartUpdaterUI", "Menu"))

import resource_rc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    smartUpdaterUI = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_smartUpdaterUI()
    ui.setupUi(smartUpdaterUI)
    smartUpdaterUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You could provide a [mcve] to indicate where the error is.

Comment: @eyllanesc i have added some pictures

Comment: @eyllanesc the problem seems in the setup of the welcome page here is a glance of the code

Comment: @eyllanesc what do u need to know exactly ? the problem  is well explained with words and pictures and i shared the part of code where the problem is located and everything is good, bye !!!

Comment: Showing "part of the code" is not a [MCVE]. Most people want to try out code that reproduces the error instead of tedious code proof reading.

Comment: but it's very long code stack overflow won't let me share it all... i will try to share it

Comment: @codingstate Please do not share all of your code. As stated in the linked article: Either generate a minimal example that shows the problem or reduce or code as much as possible while still showing the problem.

Comment: @Mailerdaimon gimme few minutes please :)

Comment: @codingstate sure. Take all the time you need. I justed wanted to hint you in a good direction to improve your question so that more people are able and willing to help you. I am pretty sure that, with good example code, you will get an answer to your question!

Comment: @Mailerdaimon done, please take a look on the code

Comment: @Mailerdaimon I just want to say thank you for helping. You helped out someone who is just starting without being rude or only sending a link to the help center over and over. We need more people like you on the site.

Comment: @Mailerdaimon thank you very much for your kindness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's pretty confusing but it's working !! i just converted .qrc file again again and it's working well now

Comment: Glad to hear it is working! To let everyone know that your Question has been answerd you can mark any of the answers as accepted (green tick mark). You can accept your own answer after 48 hours (to give others the time to post an answer as well). You can change the accepted answer at any time if e.g. a new (better answer) is given in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it worked for me.

What you should check:

- Is the file path correct `:/img/img/main menu.png`?
- Try to put the image on your disk and retry
- Try to put the image on your disk with a simple name like `D:/im.png`
- Try to use an image that is already working for another page
- Check that your ressource file is compiled (you can find a call to `rcc.exe` in the compiler log in Qt Creator).

From the Qt side of things it looks good.

Comment: yes all points that u have mentionned are good i even tried an image that is already working for another page it's working well... that's confusing.

Comment: it's working !  i just tried to convert .qrc file again and again and it's working now ! thank you